# How to create a stripped down version of R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a minimal/stripped-down version of R.  The goal is a small footprint on disk. RTerm should boot-up and support basic features like creating built-in types (matrix, array, list, etc.) and simple math (like matrix multiplication).  I'm using the standard Windows installation for 2.15.3.

Here's what I've successfully removed so far:

- all files in root directory
- Most libraries.  I removed all libraries not attached by default.
- The 'doc' directory
- The 'tests' directory
- The 'tcl' directory
- The 'src' directory
- The 'include' directory
- The 'share' directory

So I'm left with the following directories:

- bin
- etc
- library (see above)
- modules

Any bad consequences for the above?  What else can I safely remove?

Comment: My comment from earlier translates to: whenever you take something out of a distribution... you are losing something.  I can understand the need for "compressed" distributions of something like R... but this style of "stripping-down-customization" might end up making for more work (for you... or for whoever is using this particular distribution) with each new version of R.

Comment: In most cases I would agree with you, but my scenario is benign.  The only "consumer" will be some test automation (NOT R package testing, testing communication with the R program).  Its quite controlled.

Comment: Not sure how to do this in Windows, but you probably could monitor which files get accessed while performing the operations you require. Any file not touched can be removed.

Comment: Just out of interest could you eleborate on the usecase for doing this?

Comment: I'm with @Hansi. Disk space is cheap. Why bother?

Comment: @Hansi - sure!  I'm using the RserveCLI library to talk to Rserve.  It enables .net <-> R communication.  It works really well.  But testing the library is a pain.  You have to point it to Rserve.  Rserve must be pre-launched and waiting for connection.  In other words, you need integration tests.  Anyone who has written integration tests knows its a pain because of the external dependencies.  So I've converted this into a unit testing situation by simply embedding R into the Test project and creating a small wrapper class that launches R/Rserve and creates the connection.

Comment: ...now I have a sweet setup - I can write any test that tests communication between the RserveCLI library and R, WITHOUT manually running RServe external to the Test project.  Its open source on github.  Git doesn't like binary files and I don't want a huge repo.  Also, MSbuild is not great at dealing with static content.  Files often get locked up.  I'm trying to keep the footprint small to reduce friction.

Comment: btw, here's the github repo: https://github.com/SurajGupta/RserveCLI2  Take it for a spin!

Comment: *Shudder* May be this is the only way to do it on windows, but it feels very kludgy.

Comment: @hadley - I'm curious, what specifically feels kludgy? Using TCP to access a service (in this case R) from another service (in this case a .net library) is pretty standard. Self-hosting the service in the client's Test project is also pretty standard stuff.  Keeping the self-hosted service small seems reasonable.  Also, it seems that a bunch of the R install is not actually needed to run R!

Comment: @SFun28 Putting in a binary in your test distribution, which is inherently single platform. I'd also worry about cutting down the distribution: if a test fails, is it because you cut out the wrong thing?

Comment: @hadley - Yes, that is a valid concern!  In this case, the library's job is simply to send commands to R, read the basic data types from R, and push the basic data types to R.  The scenario is narrowly scoped, so I don't think it will be a problem.  But I would certainly be afraid to trim down R if the library had a broader scope.

Comment: You can probably strip the debug symbols from the binaries. I am not familiar with how to do this in windows but in linux world you can use the strip tool. Debug symbols can take up quite a bit of space. Don't do shared libraries though, I would be careful with shared libraries though. Can render a .so / dll useless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I stuck with what I posted.  Has been working flawlessly.  There's probably an opportunity to cut more, but the suggested cuts result in much small footprint.